Give the ball away cheaply
What does "give the ball away cheaply" mean in this sentence?

8 minutes: Romania 0 Ukraine 0
Ukraine are having the best of the possession, a lot going through Mudryk on the left flank. However, they give the ball away cheaply and Romania break.


They fail to make the other team 'pay a high price' (make a big effort, play hard) to get control of the ball. They do not put up much resistance probably.

What specifically is your problem: "give (the ball) away" or "cheaply"?

It could be a matter of inattention or failure to be organised in defence of the ball, not simply lack of vigour.

A momentary lapse on the part of the players who lost possession of the ball rather than skillful playing on the part of the team that won possession of the ball. Could be they made a weak pass that was easily intercepted.
